# Swift, Change width of UICollectionViewCell and UILabel(inside the cell) programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I've set the width of a cell(UICollectionViewCell) to be equal to the width of the UICollectionView and I'm trying to do exactly the same thing with the UILabel that is included inside that cell. I think the code below explains exactly what I'm trying to achieve. So i've read some question here in SO and also a couple of tutorials but I'm still not sure how I can achieve this.

In a couple of questions it was saying about using `collectionViewLayout` but I'm really struggling on how to use it within my code. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LocationViewCell
    cell.locationLabel.text = "Hello there!"

    // Set cell & label width to 100%
    let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width
    cell.frame.size.width = collectionViewWidth // Works
    cell.locationLabel.frame.size.width = collectionViewWidth // Does NOT
```

#### Update 1

So I added the following:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Set cell width to 100%
    let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: 35)
}
```

What happens is that when the view is loaded the UILabel's width is still small. If I go to another view and then return back then it's 100%. So I have to do something in the `viewDidLoad()` right? I'm already using `self.collectionView.reloadData()` but I guess that's only for data.

#### Update 2

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("locationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LocationViewCell
    cell.locationLabel.text = "Hello UILabel"

    // Set cell width to 100%
    let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.size.width
    cell.frame.size.width = collectionViewWidth
    cell.locationLabel.frame.size.width = collectionViewWidth

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The Update 1 helped me see that I should be comparing to the collection view size, not the view controller size.. thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't work because by the time this method is called, the collection view already knows how big the cell should be because it has got it from the flow delegate method:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
             sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

This is where you should be setting the size of your cells.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion. It almost works but the first time it shows up it's still small. If I go to another view and then go back, it's the width I want. How can I make it so that it shows the right width in the beginning?

Comment: How are you sizing the label within the cell?

Comment: I added the exact code in the question. So basically i'm using `cell.locationLabel.frame.size.width`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and see what the sizes that come out are. I think you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: Well I can see that the value of `collectionViewWith` is correct and it gets run before the view loads. But I guess that maybe the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` function that you suggested doesn't run **only** for the first time that the view loads.

Comment: **Solved**! So the code you suggested sets the width of the **cell**. The issue I was having after adding your code, was that I had to set the **UILabel's** width. I did that by adding constrains from the MainStoryboard(**Selected the label and added 0 spacing from the left & right of the nearest neighbour**)! Thought I should let other people know how they can do that! Thanks!

Comment: @ManolisC. Doesn't it feel better to have worked this out yourself (with a little gentle pushing) than to just have someone give you the answer? :)

Comment: Yeees! :D It's the first time I'm using a UICollectionView so I'm a bit lost but I guess I'm more confident now! Had to "clone" a `UIPickerView` because the we are not allowed to changed its height. But now with the `UICollectionView` I feel I can do lots of stuff! Thank you once again!