# How can I get a UICollectionViewCell to be the entire width of the device?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UIView` inside my `UICollectionViewCell` that I need to be reproduced. I need this view to be pinned to the left and right of the screen. However, I can't find any way to control the width of the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't play by the same AutoLayout rules as other views. Each cell is controlled by a layout class set on the `UICollectionView`.

Technically, you can drag the handles in Interface Builder and resize that way but it won't be dynamic for different screen widths and orientations.

I can think of two options:

1. Override the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` in the view controller and set to width of parent container programmatically. See Update 1 on [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677956/swift-change-width-of-uicollectionviewcell-and-uilabelinside-the-cell-program?rq=1) for how this is done or check out the [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) for more background information
2. Consider using a UITableView if all cells will always be full width

Answer (score 2):

You can use collectionView layouts. This code should help you:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var size = CGSize.zero

    if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        size = layout.itemSize;
        size.width = collectionView.bounds.width
    }

    return size
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```